# All data sets at the first column while reading csv file

Tags: python, pandas

[This is a task (in Russian)](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_6a17eab0644cadf79d4c20d6dafa4cea_titanic-assignment.pdf?Expires=1541635200&Signature=aze~m6EovAqBl6YwZiQ7od1a4IBxiIz6jL2kodG3aOrNQpqrjFBnDlpvTybjODtLRvhDjTtwW-ID5FPUqmB-Int1gmFqlRD828VoKnow2Uerc8Ve0Xkc3QG6jJatTdIO8vuqG-qQSZCaubUz5kESg2hd0NzY4lQ8EwTG7c9QmQY_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

I have a csv file separated by commas

[image]

and while reading this all the data sets at the first colomn without separating.

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\titanic.csv' )
print(data[:5])
```

And i get

```
PassengerId             ...        Embarked

0  1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/...    ...          NaN

1  2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Br...    ...          NaN

2  3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,S...    ...          NaN
```

How can i make them separate colomn by colomn?

Comment: They already will be. `print(data.iloc[:,5])`? You need 2D indexing

Comment: even the input file screenshot you have doesn't look like csv

Comment: the problem is it might recognize this as one column in a csv. Copy paste the whole file into a notepad and paste it into a excel sheet again and try saving it as a csv

Comment: You know guys, nerves are sometimes very helpful. I've just deleted all files and deleted all code. And when I downloaded the file today and wrote the same code...it becomes work)
Thanks for your comments and sorry for badly explained question since it is my the first one in SO.

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open('titanic.csv', 'r')
data = {}
for line in f:
    line = line.split(',')
    # convert to datatypes
    print(line[0]) #this will print first column of each row
f.close()
```

For pandas, just do:

```
print(data.iloc[:,0])
```

Comment: He's reading in the file as a dataframe with pandas. This isn't necessary.

Comment: Absolutely not; this comes with all sorts of issues processing a CSV

Comment: It doesn't close the file. It splits on commas regardless of whether they're strings in a single column. It doesn't work with pandas.

Comment: I did; all 6 lines of it and gave you a list of 3 things that are incorrect.

Comment: Actually that's what i need , but i need this using pandas to manipulate data.

Comment: I've taken this code in one of Coursera course and just copied it. I can attach a pdf  with the task.